# How to create secure (TLS/SSL) browser-trusted certificate for offline network

Tags: node.js, web-services, security, ssl

Trying to create a secure certificate for the local network, but I can't get the green tick from the browser without accepting the certificate manually.

In order to ensure security while keeping it as user-friendly as possible, I'd like to get the green tick in the browser (aka, trusted certificate) instead of the annoying warning message. I've tried various instructions, but it seems that every one of them requires using Let's Encrypt/Certbot (which, obviously, requires an Internet connection) or accept self-signed certificate manually (keep "proceed" in a web browser, Chrome for example).

But, this app is intended to create a local network, which under the condition of not having the Internet connection. Also, due to a large, unknown number of clients, accepting the certificate manually is, clearly, not practical. And, the user isn't a developer, so I want to avoid complex commands in cmd as best as possible, and, prefer direct implementation or automatic configuration process, if possible.

Can someone please suggest any solution?

Comment: (now) crossdupe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/239368/how-do-you-implement-an-ssl-certificate-for-a-private-intranet-site and more linked there